# Java Joda time is unable to parse DateTimeFormat::longTime

Tags: java, parsing, time, jodatime

I've encountered with Joda recently and I am having trouble parsing [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) as demonstrated on a simple snippet:

```
String localTimeString = LocalTime.now().toString(dateTimeFormatter);
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(localTimeString, dateTimeFormatter);
```

The results vary according to `DateTimeFormatter` used:

1. `DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");`
2. `DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.longTime();`

I am surprised by the result:

1. The first one works fine, the `localTimeString` has the value of `13:23:45` and printing the parsed `localTimeString` results in `13:23:45.000` correctly.
2. Here I struggle. the `localTimeString` is `1:23:45 PM`, however, the following line results in an exception:

   > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1:23:45 PM " is too short

Neither I found any similar question nor the Joda JavaDoc has helped me.

Why [`DateTimeFormat::longTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#longTime--) is unable to parse itself? I suppose I do something wrong - what is it?

Comment: ha! very interesting...

Comment: I see that you tagged this java-8. Have you considered using java.time? Yoda is sort of outdated now.

Comment: @JanLarsen: My mistake, I mean only Joda time.

Comment: Your pattern "hh:mm:ss" does not make sense, use either "HH:mm:ss" or "hh:mm:ss a".

Comment: @MenoHochschild: My typo, yet it's irrelevant. My question aim anywhere else. :/

Comment: I have reproduced. I just got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "3:06:03 PM " is too short`. The space after `PM` looks funny in my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t really know Joda-Time, but I have a guess that sounds qualified in my own ears. I tried this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormat.longTime().withLocale(Locale.US);

    String timeString = DateTime.now().toString(dateTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println("timeString: \"" + timeString + '"');
```

On my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone it just printed:

> timeString: "3:19:09 PM CEST"

So it seems that `DateTimeFormat.longTime()` includes a time zone abbreviation (here CEST for Central European Summer Time). So apparently what happens in your code is:

- Since `LocalTime` does not include a time zone, its `toString` method formats the time with the empty string as time zone abbreviation. It does include the space between the time and where the time zone abbreviation should have been. In the exception that you quote (and also when I reproduce it here) there is a space after `PM`.
- `LocalTime.parse` is stricter and objects to the absence of a time zone abbreviation in the string.